# Qt creator can not create windows app

Tags: qt, qt-creator

When installed QT creator  on my Ubuntu I was able to create simple console app gui app and so on  .
But when I installed it on my windows , and trying to create a project QT asks for 
target :
 Symbian,
 Qt simulator, 
 Harmattan

But  I need a simple win console app.
What im doing wrong ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you installed the correct version of the Qt SDK? There used to be a separate "Nokia Qt SDK" which only contained the libraries for the mobile targets.

[This link](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/sdk-windows-cpp) should always point you to the latest installer for the complete Windows SDK.

Comment: @Teukkam.Yes I have dowloaded this version .

Comment: OK, next step: run the SDKMaintenanceTool (this will typically exist in C:\QtSDK or whatever the installation top folder is) and check from the package manager that you have the desktop libraries installed (e.g. Desktop Qt 4.8.1 should be checked under the Desktop Qt category)

Comment: @Teukkam.I have not Desktop Qt category.

Comment: But I have QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\bin this folder .

Comment: OK, so you probably didn't choose to install desktop targets when you installed the SDK, or there was some kind of failure during the installation. Just tick the latest Desktop Qt and let the maintenance tool set it up for you.